# What is the max C# version a source generator library can target?

Tags: c#, constructor, ref, sourcegenerators, c#-7.3

Source generators should target .NET Standard 2.0. This is the last .NET Standard version that supports .NET Framework. The default C# version in latest .NET Framework releases is C# 7.3.

Suppose a source generator should be consumed by .NET Framework users that are using C# 7.3 in their consuming project. Does the generated source need to be C# 7.3 or would it be possible to push it further and avoid language features that would need newer versions of .NET?

Specifically I am interested in following C# 8 and above features:

- Explicit parameterless constructor in a struct (C# 10)
- Auto-Default structs (C# 11) (could work around that with Factory methods)
- `ref readonly` parameters(in parameters would theoretically work) (C# 12)

Since source generators output source into the consuming project/assembly, the generated source would be compiled with C# 7.3 features. Is there any way to walk around that? Can we compile specific files with other C# version?. Or can source generators output to entirely new assembly and somehow inform the compiler about the dependency(this would probably not work regardless because of partial types which must be fully defined inside an assembly)?

Edit 1:
I am using Incremental Source Generators, not ISourceGenerator.

Comment: Why not just set the [langversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)? I.e. `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` in the project file. Is there some special reason you want to use a higher lang version in the generated code than manually written code?

Comment: NET Standard 2.0 is the requirement for the generator not what the generator outputs. It does not even need to be c# code that it returns. So return whatever you want to return. The consuming project using that output needs to deal with that. And if it can cope with c# 12 features then let your Source generator create a code string that is only valid in that context.

Comment: @JonasH I listed the features the generated code will need. But if a consuming project is a .NET Framework project it probably will be C# 7.3 and then my generated code written using C# 12 constructs would not compile. At the same time It would be nice if the consuming project(which might no be my to begin with i.e. it will be open source on github) would not need to specify higher language version than is supported.

Comment: @Ralf Yes obviously I can write my generator so that it outputs C# 12 code but that could mean older C# Projects won't be able to use it. I'm researching what I could do to allow as many projects to use my generator while using features listed above.

Comment: I guess [conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation) wouldn't make the cut? ( for example `#if NET7_OR_GREATER ...` )

Comment: You can't influence how the source you generate is compiled. There might be a chance to know the context you are currently started from and then can generate different source code according to the target project.

Comment: @Fildor thanks for some reason I was thinking about generating different source based on .net or c# version but I didn't thought of conditional programming. It will help. Yet still some of this features will then not be available for older frameworks but that is to be expected. I guess I can output diagnostic messages when the implicit constructor will be called when I can't define an explicit one for example.

Comment: @Ralf Do you mean there is a way to know the version of the consuming project inside of my source generator? If yes that would help. Do you have any reference?

Comment: @patvax. Sorry i was just guessing that is could be possible to get that context information inside the genrator haven't researched on that.

Comment: Next thought. As a source generator generates something from an input file or multiple files. Could you simply at that info you need to to decide what to do to the input file(s)?

Comment: Unfortunately not since since I am doing nothing with input files. I am getting a type that is annotated with an attribute and generating partial implementation based on some additional attributes. I mean I could expect the user to provide version information in the attribute but that seems like a bad API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code generator implementation itself must target .NET Standard 2.0 but can use any C# version you want. I understand that your question pertains to the C# version of the generated code, which be lower or equal to the version of the current C# project.

Your code generator implementation can read the current C# version using the following code:

```cs
public static LanguageVersion GetLanguageVersion( this Compilation compilation )
{
  var tree = compilation.SyntaxTrees.FirstOrDefault();

  if ( tree == null )
  {
         return LanguageVersionFacts.MapSpecifiedToEffectiveVersion( LanguageVersion.Default );
  }

  return ((CSharpParseOptions) tree.Options).LanguageVersion;
}
```

Your implementation can then generate the code dynamically as needed by the current C# version.

Comment: You might want to add where the Compilation instance is coming from. GeneratorExecutionContext?

Comment: @Ralf From [IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext.CompilationProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.incrementalgeneratorinitializationcontext.compilationprovider?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.7.0).

Comment: Oh i thought we was looking at the ISourceGenerator stuff but that seems to be superseded by IIncrementalGenerator using the class you linked. Good to know.

Comment: Thank you, this + conditional compilation is at the very list a suitable workaround. With conditional compilation source generation won't get more complex than it already is, and with getting the Language version in the generator I can tailor my diagnostic outputs.